# EF Core - Can we call Include on a list of included items?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I have this query:

```
var orders1 = (from header in _context.SalesOrder.Include(nameof(SalesOrder.SalesOrderItem))
                                                    .Include(nameof(SalesOrder.Erp))
                                                    .Include(nameof(SalesOrder.OrderStatus))
                join orgNumber in _context.OrganizationNumber on header.CustomerNumber equals orgNumber.Number
                join userOrg in _context.UserOrganization on orgNumber.OrganizationId equals userOrg.OrganizationId
                where userOrg.UserId == userId && !header.Deleted && !orgNumber.Deleted && !userOrg.Deleted
                        && (header.OrderNumber == sopoNumber || header.CustomerPoNumber == sopoNumber)
                select GetSalesOrderModel(header)).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

The main table `SalesOrder`, has a one to many relationship with `SalesOrderItem`. And `SalesOrderItem` has a FK to the OrderStatus table, just as `SalesOrder` does. But I'm not sure how to add an `Include` to the list already included list of `SalesOrderItem`. Is it possible to add it straight in the query? I can do it after the fact when I populate the model object, but wanted to see if I could do it all in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here is another thing completely not related to answer but even then i am posting it here for anyone struggling with include and then include

in EFCore include(x=>x.Object).ThenInclude(y=>y.Subobject) also works great but the vs intellisence doset pick it up

**so instead of using .Include(nameof(SalesOrder.SalesOrderItem)) you can use .Include(x=>x.SalesOrderItem)**

Coming back to your question

this is a sample code below

```
 vmExecutionRepo.FilteredGet().Include(x => x.ProjectToProcess).Include(z => z.ProjectToProcess.Process)
            .Include(y => y.ProjectToProcess.Project)
            .Include(a => a.ProjectToProcess.Project.BotToWorkQueue).ThenInclude(v => v.BotToWorkQueueItem)
```

you can also try something out like this it should work

Comment: Ah. Yeah, this is perfect. I was trying to play around with it last night, but the Intellisense wasn't completing, so I thought I was doing something wrong. But this works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use ThenInclude() for each child navigation property. 
Reference: [Loading Related Data - Including Multiple Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)